# compiler warning about implicit conversion from int to double

Tags: c++

Is there any way to enable compiler warning for int to double conversion, i.e. `double value = 2;`?

This might look way too restrictive but I believe that in some cases like mathematical software such restriction might be acceptable to catch some bugs in compile time.

Target compiler is gcc/clang.

There are a lot of questions regarding double -> int conversion but vice versa I didn't find any useful information.

Comment: if you need a double, you need a double, regardless whether that double can be exactly represented.

Comment: If strong typing is important - chose a strongly typed language. There's no loss of data here, so why would the compiler warn you?

Comment: GCC (4.6.1) lists this option with `--help=warnings`:

`-Wconversion-extra` Warn about most implicit conversions.

However, when I tried it, it says:

    `cc1: warning: command line option ‘-Wconversion-extra’ is valid for Fortran but not for C [enabled by default]`

Comment: @littleadv performance reasons and historical reasons are present too therefore should stay with C++

Comment: Do you want a warning only in cases where there's a potential loss of information?  (That would apply when, for example, both `int` and `double` are 64 bits.)  Or do you want a warning for any `int`-to-`double` conversion?  If the latter, why; what bugs do you expect it to catch?

Comment: @KeithThompson Latter. I want to catch wrong overloaded function called. That is I might have two overloaded function with int/double parameter difference.

Answer (score 2):

Warning messages are compiler dependent, and compiler options for enabling or disabling them are especially so.  Without knowing what compiler you use, it's impossible to say.

In general, though, most compilers only provide warnings for lossy conversions, and `int` -> `double` is a perfectly lossless conversion on all platforms I work with.

Comment: Doesn't int to double lose precision when you have a 64-bit int that is greater than what can be represented by the mantissa of the double?

Comment: @user1118321 If `int` is 64 bits, the conversion could lose precision. But in C++, platforms where `int` is wider than 32 bits are, for the time being, very rare.

Comment: I have updated question to mention that compiler is gcc/clang