# g++ warning flag to avoid bool to double conversion

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I look for a warning compilation flag of g++  that will prevent silent conversion from bool to double.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675457/compiler-warning-about-implicit-conversion-from-int-to-double) relates to a broader question of conversion of int to double. The question was dismissed there because it's considered a lossless conversion and perfectly legal. 
However, since `bool` has another semantic meaning than simple integer, I expect that an implicit conversion from bool to double will issue a warning.

I've tried:
`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion`
on the following code without any success (no warning issued):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int foo(double var){
   return static_cast<int>(var);
}

int main(){
   std::cout << foo(5) << std::endl;
   std::cout << foo(5.1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << foo(false) << std::endl; // here I want the warning
   return 0;
}
```

I use g++ 4.9.2, but an answer suggesting using higher version is perfectly acceptable.
Thanks.

Comment: You could overload `foo` to take a bool, and then not implement the overload. That would result in a linker error. If you want a compiler error then templates could give you that.

Comment: That's possible solution for a specific case  but I seek for a general solution that will prevent inadvertent conversions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an approach that has nothing to do with `gcc`, but instead relies on another tool: `clang-tidy` has a [`readability-implicit-bool-conversion`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-implicit-bool-conversion.html) check that will warn you in this case. You need a separate static analysis check (which might take long to run, depending on your code base), but it works:

```
clang-tidy --checks=readability-implicit-bool-conversion your-file.cpp
```

yields

> ```
> [...] warning: implicit conversion bool -> 'double' [readability-implicit-bool-conversion]  
>
> std::cout << foo(false) << std::endl; // here I want the warning
>                  ^~~~~
>                  0.0
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I will wait for another day to see if there is a proper g++ answer. If not, I will accept yours as the most helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The real problem is the implicit conversion from `bool` to `int` (which is followed by a second conversion to `double`).

Booleans were added lately to the C++ language and never really considered semantically different from a number (just as there is no true character type).

As there is no narrowing of the type, finding a warning condition is difficult.

If you have the option of turning the bools to a custom class (maybe just temporarily), you can overload the conversion operators.